# SIGFPE with gcc and unsigned integers

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, c11, sigfpe

I'm getting this weird behaviour from an executable compiled with different versions of `gcc`, all emit the `SIGFPE` signal and the best part is that I have no floating point of any kind in my code; if someone could shed some light on this ... I literally don't know where to start to debug this, it's so weird and this bug is triggered by all the gcc installations that I have from `4.9` to `6.0`.

Here is a snippet that reproduces the problem

```
// Floating point exception - SIGFPE
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned int T;
int main()
{
#define N 256 
  for (T i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
      i += (i % i);
      printf("%u\t", i);
    }
}
// bug uncovered with
// gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
// gcc version 5.1.0 (GCC)
// gcc version 6.0.0 20150517 (experimental) (GCC)
// using -std=c11 or -std=c99
```

The purpose of this code is to reproduce the problem, I know that the logic of it doesn't really make too much sense ( the modulo part ) but `clang` passes the test, no version of `gcc` does the same and I would like to know why if there is a technical explanation for this kind of behaviour .

Comment: `i % i` divide by 0.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY a number modulo itself should result in `0`, I can't see the "division" you are mentioning or the problem in general . There should be no problem in adding the result of a modulo operation .

Comment: Division is done when determining the remainder. try `i += (i % i);` change to `i += 0;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you post a complete answer and expand on that? I don't really get what you are mentioning.

Comment: @gzp: `0 % 0` is undefined (just like `0 / 0`), so generates a SIGFPE...

Comment: @ChrisDodd ok, I get the math, I don't get why floating point computation gets involved in this at all when I use an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Does it still behave badly without the typedef?

Comment: @ChrisDodd to be clear my point is not about the logic of the math involved, it's about why something related to floating point computation kicks in while doing integer math .

Comment: @gzp: No floating point is invovled.  Its a historical accident that POSIX calls the signal `SIGFPE` even though it is generated for all numerical exceptions, both integer and floating point.  `SIGFPE` has subcodes `FPE_INTDIV` (div/mod by zero) and `FPE_INTOVF` (overflow) which can be generated by integer instructions.

Comment: @ChrisDodd that's just like watching the world burn ... it makes no sense at all even as an historical accident; how do you confuse floating-point with integers and manage to smash them together under the same label ? It really is an achievement .

Comment: @gzp: Do you understand the phrase "historical reasons"? Just take it as a general arithmetic exception. Chainging it would break too much existing legacy software. Banking software for instance does notoriously rely on established behaviour. You're welcome to re-write billions of code (including COBOL and FORTRAN). Further explanation: decent CPUs only had floating point exceptions, but none for integer division. That was actually catched by program code.

Comment: @Olaf I would really like to know how this happened, there must be a real explanation of what happened in that room where someone wrote specs for this signals ...

Comment: @gzp: How about searching the web, digging in historical stuff (news archives might be a good start). But do not annoy or blame ppl here, it is not their fault (well, unless there is one here who actually defined that - possible, but not likely). You already got an answer to your question. That is not a forum!

Comment: @Olaf I'm not blaming anyone, I'm just trying to expand and discuss

Comment: @gzp: C11 draft, 6.5.5#5: "The result of the / operator ...  the result of the % operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined." So, you can get anything. Do not complain if demons crawl up your keyboard.

Comment: @gzp: Just again: This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum! You've got your answer on two levels now (C and POSIX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running the code, this was under cygwin, gdb dumped the trace.

```
$ cat sigfpe.exe.stackdump
Exception: STATUS_INTEGER_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO at rip=00100401115
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=000000000022CB20 rcx=0000000000000001
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=000000060003A2F0 rdi=0000000000000000
r8 =0000000000000000 r9 =0000000000000000 r10=0000000000230000
r11=0000000000000002 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000001
r14=000000000022CB63 r15=000000000022CB64
rbp=000000000022CAD0 rsp=000000000022CAA0
program=C:\cygwin64\home\luser\sigfpe.exe, pid 6808, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
0000022CAD0  00100401115 (00000000020, 30001000000FF00, 0018004830F, 0000022D680                                                                                                                )
0000022CBC0  00180048380 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  0018004607C (00000000000, 0003E704021, 00000000000, 0000000002D)
00000000000  00180046114 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  00100401191 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  00100401010 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  000772E59CD (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  0007741B981 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
End of stack trace
```

The clue is in the operation `i += (i % i)`

when the loop is initial value of 0, of course, divide by zero error.

Have you tried to catch the signal?

Look at the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) on Page 265, **SIGFPE** - *an erroneous arithmetic operation, such as zero divide or an operation resulting in overflow*

It is not a compiler bug, that is implementation defined.

Comment: no, I just run this inside `gdb` and got the `SIGFPE` which was the weirdest possible possible for me and I didn't check further because I was mislead by the naming of this signal and convinced that the problem was somewhere else or part of a gcc bug . naming an integer-related signal like that is a really a poor choice .

Comment: by the way `clang` optimize this out completely, probably some dead code elimination, there is no trace of the modulo operation in the assembly generated by `clang`, that's why it runs .

Comment: It is not a bug at all, in fact, its standard, [C 11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), on page 265, *SIGFPE - an erroneous arithmetic operation, such as zero divide or an operation
resulting in overflow*

Comment: yes, my problems start when you starting naming your dog "cat", and your cat "dog" . this was a discovery for me and I really think it's just an error ; it's not even about the math of the modulo at this point, it should be considered an error emitting a signal with that name in this case.

Comment: It actually is UB: 6.5.5#5; And 7.14#4 makes this signal (among most others) optional.

Comment: @gzp SIGSEGV covers all sorts of memory access errors too, not just accessing the wrong segment.  You can only pack so much info into 3 or 4 letters, at the end of the day there's no substitute for reading the documentation of what that signal means.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: well, if 17576 or 456976 combinations are not enough, we might include other unicode letters. "umlauts" come into my mind ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Do not complain if demons crawl up your keyboard when using undefined behaviour (UB):

> C11 draft, 6.5.5#5: "The result of the / operator ... the result of
>   the % operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of
>   the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined."

UB can be anything. You should actually be happy to get an exception, whatever it is called (it actually does even show the correct reason) and not just have the program produce wrong results unnoticed (the worst that can actually happen!).
For many CPUs, you will not notice anything. Just enable compiler warnings; that might help detect such cases (yet not guranteed).